# CodeLite 10.0.1 cannot autocomplete for iterators?

Tags: c++, c++11, ide, codelite

I'm programming C++11 on Ubuntu 16.04 using CodeLite 10.0.1.

A snippet from my project is as follows:

```
#include "llvm/Pass.h"
#include "llvm/IR/Function.h"
#include "llvm/Support/raw_ostream.h"
#include <map>
#include <string>

.............

    for (Function::iterator bb = F.begin(), e = F.end(); bb != e; ++bb) {
        bb-> // NO AUTOCOMPLETE SUGGESTIONS
        // assign integer ids to BasicBlock's
        if (bb->hasName()) {
            bbNameToId[bb->getName()] = bbId++; 
        } else {
            bb->setName(Twine(bbName + std::to_string(bbId)));
            bbNameToId[bb->getName()] = bbId++;
        }

        for (BasicBlock::iterator i = bb->begin(), e = bb->end(); i != e; ++i) {
            if(opCounter.find(i->getOpcodeName()) == opCounter.end()) {
                opCounter[i->getOpcodeName()] = 1;
            } else {
                opCounter[i->getOpcodeName()] += 1;
            }
        }
    }
```

Now, CodeLite can easily do autocomplete suggestions for Functions like `F` in the code above. However, there are no suggestions for `bb->`, which is a `Function::iterator`. Also, code completion works for everything declared in the C++ standard library.

The code completion search path is set up as follows:

```
/usr/include
/usr/include/c++/5
/usr/include/c++/5/backward
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/5
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/include
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/include-fixed
/usr/local/include
```

and the project builds fine. I've enabled both CTags and Clang completion.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You should enable clang code completion within CodeLite.
From: `Settings->Code Completion->Clang->Enable clang code completion`

Next, run:
`Workspace->Parse workspace - incremental`

Comment: What does the "incremental" version do that the non-incremental version doesn't?

Comment: The "Incremental" only generates `compile_commands.json` while the full version clears the cache and parses everything. The clang code completion only requires the file `compile_commands.json`. Both will generate it, but the "incremental" version will do it much faster :)

Comment: But shouldn't I have experienced full code completion already?

Comment: I mean I've used the IDE for some time now.

Comment: CodeLite has 2 completion engines: clang and built-in. The clang is not enabled by default, so if you did not enable it from the beginning, it would not have kicked in. CodeLite will try to complete with the built-in engine, if this fails, it will fall back to the clang completion. If after enabling clang, you still don't get completion, have a look at the `clang` tab at the output view - you should see some useful information there

Comment: Sorry, but your suggestion doesn't work. The code completion is incomplete.